# How to insert content in page with limited width

Tags: html, css

I need to insert into existing html page some block that should be 100% width, responsive to dynamic content and this block should not overlap on a next one. Styles and html can be changed only for grey block.

[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sunset-fercp?file=/src/styles.css:0-365) - you can edit it.

Apllication - chrome widget will find [all comments](https://vk.com/wall-23422116_286653) on page and insert after them grey block. I cannot change app styles, only thing that i know is position of the comments div. My block get inserted after it.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const str =
  "START=SOME CONTENT --------- -------------- --------- -------------- --------- -------------- --------- -------------- --------- -------------- --------- -------------- --------- --------------  =END";
const str2 =
  "START=PROBLEM BLOCK 1) I NEED TO BE 100% window WIDTH 2)I need to be not on top of next block _ --------- -------------- -------- =END";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="cfc">
      <h1>Problem</h1>
      <div className="width-limited">
        <div className="blue">{str}</div>

        {/*only this block and this block styles can be changed*/}
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="block grey">{str2}</div>
        </div>
        {/*only this block and this block styles can be changed*/}

        <div className="red">{str}</div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <div className="width-limited blue">{str}</div>
      <div className=" grey">{str2}</div>
      <div className="width-limited red">{str}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.cfc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.width-limited {
  width: 500px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: the 500px is known? of variable?

Comment: @TemaniAfif i think it's fixed value, at least i can find and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative margin:

```css
.cfc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.width-limited {
  max-width: 500px;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
   margin:0 calc((500px - 100vw)/2);
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
.block {
   margin:0 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="cfc">
  <div class="width-limited">
    <div class="blue">{str}</div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block grey">{str2}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">{str}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can consider `min()` to optimize the code and get rid of the media query:

```css
.cfc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.width-limited {
  max-width: 500px;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
   margin:0 min(0px, (500px - 100vw)/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="cfc">
  <div class="width-limited">
    <div class="blue">{str}</div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block grey">{str2}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">{str}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with

```
width: 100vw;
```

It will take de 100% width of the display

If you want to appear on top you must have to edit the parent, wrapper in this case:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Change the position to absolute instead of relative.

Comment: Nice, but there is 2 problems - start and overlapp: https://i.imgur.com/RY8zIy3.png