# Expand image outside of percentage width container

Tags: css

I have an image which sits inside a centered div of text:

```
<div style="max-width: 64rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <img style="width: 100%;" src="myimage.png">
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

I want to have a nice arty effect where the image sits centered, but pops outside the parent div of text on both sides by 3rem or so.

I'd love to do this with with rem values and negative margins, but I've basically given up trying to get it centered with negative margins.

What's annoying me more is that I can't even do it with percentage values, as the following doesn't work:

```
<div style="max-width: 64rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <img style="width: 120%; margin-left: -10%;" src="myimage.png">
</div>
```

I've seen some suggestions of using viewport width and `calc` but they seem to require setting a pixel value for the parent div, which won't work in this case. Am I missing something obvious in getting the image to overhang the parent container and maintain some dynamic widths?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62915903/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd love to do this with with rem values and negative margins, but I've basically given up trying to get it centered with negative margins.

It won’t center properly of course, if the width is still 100% - trying to drag the image out at *both* sides by -3rem, *and* have it have 100% width of the parent at the same time, constructs a constraint that can not completely be fullfilled.

So - adapt the width accordingly!

```
<img style="width:calc(100% + 6rem); margin:0 -3rem;" src="…">
```

Comment: Works like a charm in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lujk2zb/ Unfortunately on my page it's failing to resize the image and just pulling the image out to the left (i.e. not equally on both sides). But it's obviously a problem elsewhere in my CSS, so marked as the correct answer!

Comment: @Nick check if the image has a `max-width: 100%` applied perhaps, that is common in “responsive image” scenarios, but here in this specific instance that would have to be modified the same way as the width then.

Comment: it was being added by the CSS reset stylesheet and I didn't spot it <facepalm> . Thank you x2!